# Samsung Galaxy S1 Constant Reboot Cycle

Tags: boot-loop

I left my Samsung Galaxy S1 charging overnight plugged into my computer (as I usually do) and when I came to use it in the morning, it was turned off (to my surprise).
When I turned it on, it goes into a constant reboot cycle, where it turns on, gets to the home screen and then about half a minute after, just reboots itself again.

I am able to get into recovery mode and download mode and I can keep it stable in safe mode - but have limited access to apps.
My questions are:

(a) does anyone know what would have caused this?
(b) what can I do to stop it?! without the obvious factory reset?
(c) I originally thought it was a battery problem but now that I can sustain it in recovery and safe mode, am I right in saying that the battery is fine and its most probably a software or app malfunction?

Answer (score 1):

As you stated you can go to *safe mode* fine, the conclusion is clear: One of your apps is causing this issue. If you can remember what you installed lately, immediately before the trouble started, that's the most likely candidate. You can use *safe mode* to uninstall this malfunctioning app -- that's what's *safe mode* is for.

**To your a-b-c:**
a) see above: a mal-functioning app is the most likely candidate.
b) again see above: boot to *safe mode*, and uninstall the evil-doer
c) yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Does your sdcard have multiple partitions?

Most recoveries have built-in repair function to scan corruptions in sdcards which prevents your phone from booting properly, it is under Mount -> Repair if you are using CWM.

If it did not help, try removing your sdcard temporarily to check if it boots up properly. If it successfully boots then you need to reformat your sdcard, make sure to backup first.

Comment: Thanks for that.
I do have an external SD card, but I'm running a CROM version of Jellybean 4.1.1 on the Galaxy S1 and since installing that, have had no access to the external SD card.
I just played with all the apps in safe mode and found one that kept crashing the system - I deleted it and re-installed it and now the phone booted up properly and seems to be running well..for now!
I'm using Devil Kernel - how can I check for the built in repair you mentioned?

Comment: It is part of the CWM recovery. You have to boot your phone in recovery mode and access the mount (or sometimes in advance) menu. You will find the option there.